# Calculated field for a QuerySet with a large number of items

Tags: django, django-models

I want to add an extra (calculated) field on the fly for each item in a QuerySet whith thousand items.

For performance reasons, this field must be calculated in for a bunch of entities, and not for each singular item.

What is the most elegant form to integrate that in models?

Comment: you can use case with annotation. and i vote to close your question as too broad.

Comment: This is absolutely impossible to answer. You haven't given us any details of what you are trying to achieve, what the models look like, or what the calculation would be.